# Change dependency of php-sass compiler

Tags: laravel, sass, composer-php

I want to use the scss compiler for Laravel: https://github.com/panique/laravel-sass. This uses v0.0.14 of leafo/scssphp as a compiler. To upgrade this to the latest version (now v0.7.1) I need to make a change in the composer.json.

But whatever I try, when running `composer update` I get the notification that `panique/laravel-sass dev-master requires leafo/scssphp v0.0.14`.

What is the correct way to upgrade the compiler?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the `composer.json` of lavarel-sass in https://github.com/panique/laravel-sass/blob/master/composer.json, there is an explicit dependency to v0.0.14 of scssphp. You cannot change this, this needs to be done by the maintainer of lavarel-sass. And even providing ways to override this will cause lavarel-sass to stop working correctly, as the gap between 0.0.14 and 0.7.1 is huge

Comment: Or should I just fork it and try to get it working? What do you recommend?

Comment: The package looks abandoned, with the last commit being three years old. So fork it or find another package to suit your needs